# ¿Cómo se coloca un rectángulo para escanear en una cámara?

Tags: python, opencv

Mi pregunta es esa, quiero lograr algo como lo siguiente:

[image: Al alinear los números los lee]

Poner un área en la cual se lean los datos.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Un ejemplo sencillo para que se guíe a partir de el:

Suponga que desea escanear una foto con un rectángulo y este rectángulo debe recorrer toda la imagen. Asumiendo que el rectángulo tiene un tamaño de 20

```
 for i in range(0,height):
    for j in range(0,width):
       pt1 = (i, j)
       pt2 = (pt1.x+20, pt1.y+20)
       point.append([pt1,pt2])
       cv2.rectangle(res,pt1,pt2,(255,0,0))
```

Es algo sencillo solo como guía.

> [Aquí hay un buen ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243712/8933039) sobre detectar las caras, creo que esto puede servirle para ampliar su conocimiento.(Traducir del Inglés)